# can't access an element ref in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, modal-dialog, ref

I'm trying to implement a modal with React, in this modal I want to position the modal relative to the the element which triggered it (which is not a parent).
In this set up I can access the the reference to the triggering element like you see here

```
        console.log(
          "console button triggering modal offset" + event.target.offsetTop
        );
```

but I can't access the reference to the modal, this code generate an error

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("loggin ref width   " + modalRef.current.offsetWidth);
  }, [modalRef]);
```

I have this error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetWidth')
    at UserParamModal2.js:44:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
```

When I remove the CSSTransition component every thing is fine,
here is the full code.
I would appreciate any help.

```
import {
  React,
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./UserParamModal2.css";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

const UserParamModalOverlay = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const content = (
    <div className={`userparammodal ${props.className}`} ref={ref}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    content,
    document.getElementById("modal-user-param")
  );
});

const UserParamModal2 = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const modalRef = useRef();

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
    return {
      toggle(event) {
        console.log(
          "console button triggering modal offset" + event.target.offsetTop
        );
        setVisible((prev) => {
          return !prev;
        });
      },
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("loggin ref width   " + modalRef.current.offsetWidth);
  }, [modalRef]);

  return (
    <CSSTransition
      in={visible}
      mountOnEnter
      unmountOnExit
      timeout={200}
      classNames="userparammodal"
    >
      <UserParamModalOverlay {...props} ref={modalRef}></UserParamModalOverlay>
    </CSSTransition>
  );
});

export default UserParamModal2;
```

Answer (score 1):

To assign that trigger modal to the element, you can use the useRef hook to get a reference to the triggering element and then calculate the state of the modal based on that reference Here is a general outline of how you can achieve this.

Get a reference to the triggering element: After defining the modal triggering element, in the parent component, use the useRef hook to create a ref for the triggering element.

Calculate the modal state: In the modal component, use the useEffect hook to calculate the state of the modal based on the state of the triggering element. You can use methods like getBoundingClientRect() to get the shape and location of the trigger object.

Use position styles: Set the position of the modal using inline styles or CSS classes based on calculated space.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import UserParamModal2 from "./UserParamModal2";

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const triggerRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={triggerRef} onClick={() => UserParamModal2.toggle()}>
        Open Modal
      </button>
      <UserParamModal2 triggerRef={triggerRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;




import React, { forwardRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const UserParamModal2 = forwardRef(({ triggerRef }, ref) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const triggerElement = triggerRef.current;

    if (triggerElement) {
      // Calculate the position of the modal relative to the trigger element
      const { top, left, height, width } = triggerElement.getBoundingClientRect();

      // Apply position styles
      // You can adjust these values based on your requirements
      const modalStyle = {
        top: `${top + height + 10}px`,
        left: `${left}px`,
      };

      // Apply the styles to the modal
      // In this example, we set it as inline styles, but you can use CSS classes too
      // Be sure to apply "position: absolute;" to the modal container
      Object.assign(ref.current.style, modalStyle);
    }
  }, [triggerRef]);

  // The rest of your modal code

  return (
    <div ref={ref} className={`userparammodal ${visible ? "visible" : ""}`}>
      {/* Modal content */}
    </div>
  );
});

export default UserParamModal2;
```

Comment: hi vijay, thanks for the code, actually i would want to access le modal ref (to have the width of the modal and center it horizontally to the trigger element, yet i have questions concerning your code 1) in UserParamModal2 you have triggerRef and ref but in the parent component you got only this triggerRef={triggerRef} how is thtat ? 2) you said i could  use css classes but the position is dynamique how to achieve it (without using styled components) ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `modalRef.current` is `undefined` when useEffect runs for the first time. Just add null check or `if(modalRef.current)` condition to avoid this error.

You may also need to update the dependency if useEffect doesn't run.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("loggin ref width   " + modalRef.current?.offsetWidth);
  }, [modalRef.current]);
```

Comment: Hi @Mayank kumar Chaudhari, i did, still the same error message

Comment: What error message do you see?

Comment: i just added the error message in the question

Comment: Just add ? like `modalRef.current?.offsetWidth` and try.

Comment: yes it does not throw an error but it still undefined